# PowerMock argument captor returns null for new Intent

Tags: android, powermockito

Here is my main class and the method that I'm trying to test

```
public class MyClass {

    public void startEmailActivity(FragmentActivity activity, @NotNull String emailUrl) {
        if (isMyEmailAppInstalled()) {
            Intent myEmailAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(emailUrl));
            myEmailAppIntent.setClassName(MY_PACKAGE_NAME, MY_EMAIL_COMPOSE_ACTIVITY_EMAIL);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }
```

And here is the test class and method. Assume that I've mocked necessary calls inside isMyEmailAppInstalled() method such that it returns true

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Uri.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    FragmentActivity mockActivity;
    @Mock
    private Uri mockUri;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Intent> intentArgumentCaptor;

    private static final String MOCK_EMAIL_URL = "mailto:mock@mock.com";

    @Test
    public void testStartEmailActivity() throws Exception {

        doNothing().when(mockActivity).startActivity(any(Intent.class));
        mockStatic(Uri.class);
        when(Uri.parse(MOCK_EMAIL_URL)).thenReturn(mockUri);       

        MyClass testObject = new MyClass();
        testObject.startEmailActivity(mockActivity, MOCK_EMAIL_URL);

        intentArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        verify(mockActivity).startActivity(intentArgumentCaptor.capture());
        Intent sentIntent = intentArgumentCaptor.getValue();
        //sentIntent is null here :( Below lines of code throws NPE when test is run
        Assert.assertTrue(sentIntent.getComponent().getClassName().equalsIgnoreCase(MY_EMAIL_COMPOSE_ACTIVITY_EMAIL));
        Assert.assertTrue(sentIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(MY_PACKAGE_NAME));
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea why the argument captor would return null? It seems like simple thing, may be I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found out the missing piece.
Basically I needed two things.

1. add the preparefortest for the class under test which will allow powermock to get inside this and help with mocking i.e

   @PrepareForTest({Uri.class, MyClass.class})
2. mock the construction of new object using whenNew()

   ```
   whenNew(Intent.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockIntent);
   ```

So this is what my final test method looks like

```
@Test
public void testStartEmailActivity() throws Exception {

    doNothing().when(mockActivity).startActivity(any(Intent.class));
    mockStatic(Uri.class);
    when(Uri.parse(MOCK_EMAIL_URL)).thenReturn(mockUri);       
    when(mockIntent.setClassName(MY_PACKAGE_NAME, MY_EMAIL_COMPOSE_ACTIVITY_EMAIL)).thenReturn(mockIntent);
    whenNew(Intent.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockIntent);

    MyClass testObject = new MyClass();
    testObject.startEmailActivity(mockActivity, MOCK_EMAIL_URL);
    verify(mockActivity).startActivity(mockIntent);

}
```